# Congfigure conda to create environments with default packages

Tags: python, conda

Is it possible to include additional packages by default when creating a new conda environment?

Specifically, there are some packages like `pylint` and `epc` that I'd like to have installed to make development in emacs nicer. But I occasionally forget to install these in new environments and spend some time being confused about why there aren't squiggly red lines all over the place.

I suppose I could create a bash function to wrap `conda create -n <name> pylint epc ...` but I was wondering if there was any method for doing this internal to conda itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do first an environment with the packages `pylint`, `epc`, e.t.c
Then, whenever you want to generate a new env with those libraries, just create a clone of the first with the `--clone` option

```sh
conda create -n mylibs pylint epc

conda create -n foo --clone mylibs
conda create -n bar --clone mylibs
```